# Serving assets from Nuxt config file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

[image]

I've found an online bootstrap template which I'm trying to adapt as part of a nuxt project. I've put all the bootstrap files in the static folder.

In the nuxt.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: ' Bootstrap Responsive Website Template | Home :: w3layouts',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Nuxt.js project' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/static/css/style.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/static/css/flexslider.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/static/css/easy-responsive-tabs.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/static/css/chocolat.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/static/css/bootstrap.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/static/css/font-awesome.min.css' },
    ]
  },
```

However the path is wrong and the css is not working. How can I get this working?

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets#static

Comment: You should remove the 'static'. `href: '/css/style.css'`

Comment: Your way worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS has its own Property in the Nuxt Config.
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-css/

```
header stuff....
css: [
  { '/css/style.css' },
  { '/css/flexslider.css' },
  { '/css/easy-responsive-tabs.css' },
  { '/css/chocolat.css' },
  { '/css/bootstrap.min.css' },
  { '/css/font-awesome.min.css' },
]
```

The CSS property is NOT in the header itself, it has its own point.

Note that in Nuxt the Standard Path for the Static Folder is a simple `/` if that doesn´t work you can also try out `@/static/...`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually used the approach from the comment above.